# Angular Testing return value of Function

Tags: unit-testing, angular5, karma-jasmine

I have this function that returns me a value of an array

```
  getProductTName(productTypeId: string) {
    const filteredProdType = this.producttype.find(pt => pt.product_type_id === productTypeId);
    if (typeof filteredProdType !== 'undefined' && productTypeId === filteredProdType.product_type_id) {
      return filteredProdType.name;
    }
  }
```

I tried to test it storing the value that the function returns to a variable but it shows me undefined...Is there a way to test this function

something like this:

```
it('getProductTName', () => {
   let name = component.getProductTName('id');
   console.log(name)
   expect(name).toEqual('name')
})
```

Comment: You store the result in name, and you print item...

Comment: @JBNizet i wrote it quickly, but in my code i have printed name

Comment: Then it means your function returns undefined. Probably because the if condition is false.

Comment: @JBNizet the id i enter as a parameter should not return undefined

Comment: Well, it does. So debug your code.

Comment: @JBNizet so this test code should print the name correctly?

Comment: This test fails if the returned value is not the string 'name'. it fails. Which means that the called function does not return the string 'name'. So, either the test is wrong because the function is not supposed to return 'name', but undefined, or the code is wrog because it's supposed to return 'name', but doesn't. In both cases, something is wrong. So, debug, and find it.

Comment: Can you write any example please?

Comment: Well, replace the function body by `return 'name';` and the test will pass. Maybe that will finally convince you that the problem is in your code. Debug it to know **why** it doesn't return what you think it should.